# Convert Uncommon Date Format

Tags: r, time

Is there an easy way to transform this string into a meaningful date format?

`date <- "Tue Apr 04 10:18:33 +0000 2017"`

Right now I would use some regex and then the `lubridate` package. But I guess there is a less complicated way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
as.POSIXct(date, format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
```

Comment: I had to set `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")`. Now it works.